# SQLQuery column getting filled with 1's instead of 0's

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

Please consider the following code for testing purpose:

```
CREATE TABLE Mydatabase(
  TableID_bi int,
  EVENTS VARCHAR(200),
  email VARCHAR(200),
  Timedetail DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO `Mydatabase` (`TableID_bi`,`EVENTS`, `email`, `Timedetail`) VALUES
  (1, 'first','email@gmail.com','2013-06-15' ),
(2, 'first','email2@gmail.com', '2013-06-15'),
(3, 'second','email3@gmail.com', '2013-06-15'),
(4, 'second','email4@gmail.com', '2013-06-15'),
(5, 'third','email5@gmail.com', '2013-06-15');
```

A Brief Description of what I've done with the code:

I have created a view for each of the connections, namely, first,second, third etc which is as 
follows:(The reason I haven't chosen UNION to club all the queries is because I want the results to be displayed column wise rather than row.)

```
create view firstview as 
SELECT  DATE(Timedetail) as Datefield1 ,
       count(Timedetail) as firstoccurances,
         Events  
FROM Mydatabase  
WHERE Events = "first" GROUP BY Datefield1 ;
```

Similarly for second,third and all other events.

Here is how I'm retrieving the results from the view:

```
SELECT a.Datefield1
       a.firstoccurances,
       b.secondoccurances,
       c.thirdoccurances

FROM   firstview a,
       secondview b,
       thirdview c

WHERE a.Datefield1 = b.Datefield2
AND   a.Datefield1 = c.Datefield3
```

Brief Description about what's happening in the Database:

I'm working on a large database of same kind as mentioned above. For example, I have a selected the folowing Date Range from the database: 2013-07-01 to 
2013-08-01

Now, as far as first and second events are concerned I have "first" and "second" values listed for each and every date under the EVENTS column. To be 
more precise, if I test it using COUNT() function, I can see the results like following:

For first connection:

```
TimeDetail  |  Number of first events
2013-07-01              4
2013-07-02              2
2013-07-03              6
 and so on

2013-08-01              5
```

Same is the case with second event. However, with the "third" event, it's not the same.I have "third" event listed under Events column for only couple of 
dates, say for example   2013-07-02  and 2013-07-03 and I should see the following output:

```
TimeDetail  |  Number of third events
2013-07-01              0
2013-07-02              1
2013-07-03              2
 and so on

2013-08-01              0
```

But I'm not getting the above output. Instead, all other date values except  2013-07-02  and 2013-07-03  are filled with value 1 under the "number of third"
events column. May I know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot pretend I understand the problem, but might this be the solution...

```
SELECT timedetail
     , SUM(CASE WHEN events = 'first' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) first 
     , SUM(CASE WHEN events = 'second' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) second
     , SUM(CASE WHEN events = 'third' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) third
  FROM mydatabase 
 GROUP 
    BY timedetail;
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to use COUNT here instead of SUM. It's working. :)

Comment: No, `sum` is the correct operator in the example above. Replacing it with `count` produces the  wrong results. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0006/1/0 and 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0006/2/0 .

Comment: Also, the schema you posted works fine [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0006/6/0). So you must have used different sql than what you posted, or there is something else going on in your environment that you have shared with us ;-)